# Apache Mina : No error or call back when the endpoint is not accessible

Tags: java, nio, apache-mina

I'm facing a strange issue using apache mina when connecting to a socket server. Even if the socket server is down, I'm not getting any error or call back. But if the connection to server is lost after successful connection attempt, I get notification. Has anybody else encountered this behavior?

Comment: can you show related code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding `sessionClosed()` method in your handler class? You can monitor your session state by overriding methods from `IoHandlerAdapter` class.

```
public void sessionCreated(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    }

public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    }

public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    }

public void sessionIdle(IoSession session, IdleStatus status) throws Exception {
    }

public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    }

public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
    }

public void messageSent(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
    }

public void inputClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
    }
```

Comment: It was issue in the code. The thrown exception were masked by the thread pool from which connection attempt was initiated.